# Bug "Error: INVARIANT mutate({ cadence }) -- cadence is required"

Tags: javascript, onflow-cadence

[image]

I happen this bug when I get getAccount from BE. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your fcl version, if it is less than this "@onflow/fcl": "^1.0.0",
so update it to this version, hope it will work.